# Missing Scalebar Units in QGIS3 Atlas PDF

Tags: qgis, export, pdf

Using QGIS3.0.2 on Windows10 Pro 64-bit, I create a Layout and all appears fine with Atlas Preview with scalebar units displaying above the bar as they should.  However when I export the Atlas to PDF file, the scale bar is OK but the units are missing.

[image: Preview]

[image]

Comment: Please add screenshots comparing what it looks like in preview and in the final export.